# Data from website passing variable name to URL but not going to the correct website

Tags: vba, excel

This code is basically working correctly but for some reason the data it pulls is not changing. As I step through the Name_of_Person variable is changing as I move through the X's and the URL created and used changes every time but it keeps inserting the data from the first query. Any thoughts as to why?

```
 Sub Search_People()

Dim Name_Of_Person As String
Dim URL As String
Dim Dashboard_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Dashboard_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim Data_Dump As Worksheet
Set Data_Dump = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataDump")
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Last_Row As Long
Dim Email_Output As Range
Set Email_Output = Data_Dump.Range("A:A")
Dim Cell As Range

Last_Row = Data_Sheet.Cells(Data_Sheet.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    For X = 1 To Last_Row + 1
        Name_Of_Person = Data_Sheet.Cells(2 + X, 8)
        URL = "URL;" & "https://hn.com/people/"
        URL = URL & Name_Of_Person & "%40.com"
            With Data_Dump.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            URL, _
            Destination:=Data_Dump.Range("A1"))
             .FieldNames = True
             .RowNumbers = False
             .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
             .PreserveFormatting = True
             .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
             .BackgroundQuery = True
             .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
             .SavePassword = False
             .SaveData = True
             .AdjustColumnWidth = True
             .RefreshPeriod = 0
             .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
             .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
             .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
             .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
             .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
             .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
             .WebDisableRedirections = False
             .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

            Set Cell = Email_Output.Find("Email")
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(2 + X, 9).Value = Cell
            End With
            Data_Dump.Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft



    Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: You're not using SQL, so you don't need `BackgroundQuery:=False`. I'm not sure that's the source of your issue however.

Comment: First, make sure to explicitly declare the sheet you want `Rows.Count` to run on, so make your line `Last_Row = Data_Sheet.Cells(Data_Sheet.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row`  That *could* be the source, since otherwise, your `Rows.Count` is running on the active sheet, which I assume is going to be the "Dashboard".  If you step through the code, using `F8`, what does `Last_Row` resolve to?

Comment: @BruceWayne As I step through it is at 1003.

Comment: @TIm I tried removing BackgroundQuery:=False and it broke. It only seems to work with that included.

Comment: @BruceWayne I partially fixed it to the above. It now works on the first run through then on the second one gets an "Object Required" error on Set Cell = Email... Any thoughts?

Comment: Try putting the `End With` before you `Set Cell = `...

Comment: @BruceWayne I just tried that and it is still giving me the 424 error sadly. It is only on the 2nd X  for some reason. The 1st works just fine

Comment: Hm, and when you get to your second X, you're positive that your `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataDump").Range("A:A")` has "Email", correct?

Comment: Yes. It is part of a larger block of text. For example it is formatted as EmailJohn.Doe to start with. @BruceWayne

Comment: Oh! What's that last line doing? You're deleting column A from `Data_Dump`...won't that get rid of all the cells with `Email`?

Comment: @BruceWayne It does but only after it is already inserted into the next cell. The loop has to pull data from a new URL each time through the loop so I clear the old data each time. I changed the Data_Dump.Range("A:A") to .Range("A:Z") and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Search_People()

Dim Name_Of_Person As String
Dim URL As String
Dim Dashboard_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Dashboard_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim Data_Dump As Worksheet
Set Data_Dump = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataDump")
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Last_Row As Long
Dim Email_Output As Range
Set Email_Output = Data_Dump.Range("A:XFD")
Dim Cell As Range


Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Last_Row = Data_Sheet.Cells(Data_Sheet.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    For X = 1 To Last_Row
    On Error Resume Next

        Name_Of_Person = Data_Sheet.Cells(2 + X, 8)
            Application.StatusBar = "    Pulling Data for... " & Name_Of_Person
        URL = "URL;" & "https://site/"
        URL = URL & Name_Of_Person & "site.com"
            With Data_Dump.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            URL, _
            Destination:=Data_Dump.Range("A1"))
             .FieldNames = True
             .RowNumbers = False
             .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
             .PreserveFormatting = True
             .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
             .BackgroundQuery = True
             .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
             .SavePassword = False
             .SaveData = True
             .AdjustColumnWidth = True
             .RefreshPeriod = 0
             .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
             .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
             .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
             .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
             .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
             .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
             .WebDisableRedirections = False
             .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


            End With
            Set Cell = Email_Output.Find("Email")
            Worksheets("Data").Cells(2 + X, 9).Value = Cell
            Data_Dump.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete



    Next X
            Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

This code solved all of the above issues.